# How to use Postgres' BIGSERIAL in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I would like to use PostgreSQL BIG SERIAL type as an id in Sequelize Model. How do I do this?
I found that Sequelize uses SERIAL when you do this:

```
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true // this converts INT to SERIAL for Postgres
},
```

But how to make it BIGSERIAL?

Answer (score 6):

I think your answer can be found on [this Github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1784).

Essentially, just set:

```
type: Sequelize.BIGINT, 
primaryKey: true,
autoIncrement: true
```

From the [PostgreSQL Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

> The data types serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a
> notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar
> to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases).